# Publish to Azure in Visual Studio Community for Mac

Tags: azure, visual-studio-mac

I created a brand new project in Visual Studio Community for Mac and got my Azure app service set up, ready to be deployed to. In Visual Studio, for some reason there is no publish option at all when I right click on the project itself. It is an MVC project, so this doesn't make a lot of sense. Is there something I need to do first?

[image: no publish option anywhere]

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET core project? Create an ASP.NET core project, right click the project and you should see the publish to Azure option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need Visual Studio for Mac Professional. I had the same problem, then I signed in using my work MSDN account. As soon as it registered, I was able to right click on the project and 'Publish to Azure' showed up.

Comment: Ah. That's unfortunate since Visual Studio Community for Windows allows publishing :( thank you though, I was afraid of this.

Comment: I also noticed that it was only available for Core, not regular ASP.NET MVC, since I was on a Mac maybe?

Comment: It's unfortunate that it has to be .NET Core. There are a lot of legacy .NET and Mono projects out there.

Answer (score 2):

Just use .Net Core Mvc App template. Somehow they made publishing only available for Core runtime. 
And it is not matter of Vs edition, works in Community as well.

Also:
"Note that the .NET Core 2.0 SDK needs to be installed via a separate download to enable .NET Core 2.0 development in Visual Studio 2017 for Mac Version 7.1."
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-mac-relnotes

Answer (score -1):

Publishing to Azure in Visual Studio **Community for Mac is working** perfectly for me (no need to install the Professional version). However, I also have issues with that. For me, the solution was two things:

**(1)**

Publish to Azure menu is not available for ASP.NET projects currently. We must create a ASP.NET **Core** project instead. If the project is a Core one, the Publish button will be there. Some differences:

- .NET **Core** is open source, it uses NuGet to do everything about dependencies automatic and it's easy to move from a machine to another.
- .NET (full) Framework seems more Windows related, so that's why it doesn't work for Mac / OSX well.

**(2)**

I was so confused because I thought the Publish button disappeared one day... I realise it is **not** on the context menu of the parent folder but the main one:

[image: Publish button place]